# crank nicolson - forward vs backward equations

Tags: pde

I have implemented a script in python to solve a differential equation in $(x,t)$ using the crank-nicolson method. To start with, I was testing a case in which I know a solution: $$u_{xx} + u_{x} - u - u_{t} = 0, \ \mbox{ with } \ X_{0} \leq x \leq X_{1}, \ T_{0} \leq t \leq T_{1}.$$
This is solved by
$$u(x, t) = exp(x+t),$$
if we impose appropriate boundary conditions.

I was relying on this [paper](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Erjones/bus864/notes/notes2.pdf). Though, looking at equations (16/17), the role of $A_i,$  $C_i$ seem to be inverted, so I have inverted them. The article refers to the case in which you have a condition at $T_0$, i.e. $u(x,T_0) = f(x),$ so I used the boundary condition:
$$u(x,T_0) = exp(x+T_0).$$
I also used the boundaries at the upper/lower $x-$ axis:
$$u(X_0,t) = exp(X_0+t), \ \ u(X_1,t) = exp(X_1+t),$$
using first and last equations in (18).

Until here, everything works fine. Keeping fixed $k/h^2$ and increasing $k$, the errors between the solution and the true solution $(u = exp(x+t))$ converge to zero. Here is the output:

```
N.B. N_x = 10 * multiplier,  N_t = 4 * multiplier

multiplier: 1 , N_x: 10 , N_t: 4 , k: 0.500 , h^2: 0.6400 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 0.9999

multiplier: 3 , N_x: 30 , N_t: 36 , k: 0.056 , h^2: 0.0711 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 0.1109

multiplier: 5 , N_x: 50 , N_t: 100 , k: 0.020 , h^2: 0.0256 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 0.0403

multiplier: 10 , N_x: 100 , N_t: 400 , k: 0.005 , h^2: 0.0064 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 0.0101

multiplier: 30 , N_x: 300 , N_t: 3600 , k: 0.001 , h^2: 0.0007 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 0.0011

multiplier: 100 , N_x: 1000 , N_t: 40000 , k: 0.000 , h^2: 0.0001 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 0.0001
```

I also wanted to try a couple of variations, for which I am getting problems:

1. The first variation is to use the smoothing conditions at the upper/lower $x-$boundaries, as suggested by the paper. Basically, first and last equations become:

   $u_{0,n+1} - 3\cdot u_{1,n+1} + 3\cdot u_{2,n+1} -u_{3,n+1} = 0;$

   $u_{I-3,n+1} - 3\cdot u_{I-2,n+1} + 3\cdot u_{I-1,n+1} -u_{I,n+1} = 0;$
2. The second variation is to impose the boundary condition at $T_1$ rather than $T_0$ and solve backward. For this, I have tried two methods:

   - The first method is to run the same PDEs, but backwards. Basically, in eq. (16), the recursively known vector $D_i$ becomes the LHS rather than the RHS and we solve for $u_{.,n}$ with $u_{.,n+1}$ known from previous step. I also changed the boundary conditions replacing the conditions at $t$ with $T_1-t$, i.e.:

     $b.1) \ u(x, T_1) = exp(x+T_1);$

     Then, recursively at time-step $j$:

     $b.2) \ u(X_0, (T_1-j)*d\_t) = exp(X_0+(T_1-j)*d\_t);$

     $b.3) \ u(X_1, (T_1-j)*d\_t) = exp(X_1+(T_1-j)*d\_t).$
   - The second method is to define $\tilde{u}(x, t) = u(x, T-t),$ which solves a slight variation of the original PDE. Basically, the sign of $\tilde{u}_t$ changes:
     $$\tilde{u}_{xx} + \tilde{u}_{x} - \tilde{u} + \tilde{u}_{t} = 0.$$
     Taking this into account and going through the calculations eq. 15) and 16) - unless I have made wrong calculations - what changes is that the $4\cdot h^2$ term within $B_i$ in eq. 16) - both RHS and LHS - change sign. As it comes to the boundary conditions, they are the same as $b.1)-b.3)$ above except that we need to make the change $t \rightarrow T_1-t$ only in the RHS of the equations and not in the $\tilde{u}(x, .)$, i.e:

     $b.1) \ \tilde{u}(x, T_0) = exp(x+T_1);$

     Then, recursively at time-step $j$:

     $b.2) \ \tilde{u}(X_0, j*d_t) = exp(X_0+(T_1-j)*d\_t);$

     $b.3) \ \tilde{u}(X_1, j*d_t) = exp(X_1+(T_1-j)*d\_t).$

     Then our solution is simply $u(x,t) = \tilde{u}(x, T_1-t)$

When it comes to 1. (smoothing conditions), the convergence is very slow, and I am not even sure it is converging in the first place:

```
multiplier: 1 , N_x: 10 , N_t: 4 , k: 0.500 , h^2: 0.6400 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 21.4295

multiplier: 3 , N_x: 30 , N_t: 36 , k: 0.056 , h^2: 0.0711 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 14.7544

multiplier: 5 , N_x: 50 , N_t: 100 , k: 0.020 , h^2: 0.0256 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 13.5737

multiplier: 10 , N_x: 100 , N_t: 400 , k: 0.005 , h^2: 0.0064 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 12.7183

multiplier: 30 , N_x: 300 , N_t: 3600 , k: 0.001 , h^2: 0.0007 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 12.1621

multiplier: 100 , N_x: 1000 , N_t: 40000 , k: 0.000 , h^2: 0.0001 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 11.9701
```

When it comes to 2. (boundary condition at $T_1$), the solution seems to explode:

```
forward or backward: backward , x_bound_cond: exact_solution , method_if_backward: backward_equations

multiplier: 1 , N_x: 10 , N_t: 4 , k: 0.500 , h^2: 0.6400 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 14957.2237

multiplier: 3 , N_x: 30 , N_t: 36 , k: 0.056 , h^2: 0.0711 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 7681.0148

multiplier: 5 , N_x: 50 , N_t: 100 , k: 0.020 , h^2: 0.0256 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 11680.6986

multiplier: 10 , N_x: 100 , N_t: 400 , k: 0.005 , h^2: 0.0064 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 22387.3289

multiplier: 30 , N_x: 300 , N_t: 3600 , k: 0.001 , h^2: 0.0007 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 66052.2187
-----------------------------------

forward or backward: backward , x_bound_cond: exact_solution , method_if_backward: y_tilde

multiplier: 1 , N_x: 10 , N_t: 4 , k: 0.500 , h^2: 0.6400 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 20365556.8251

multiplier: 3 , N_x: 30 , N_t: 36 , k: 0.056 , h^2: 0.0711 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 314523381202040153368016313980598438510416920683660041464578048.0000

multiplier: 5 , N_x: 50 , N_t: 100 , k: 0.020 , h^2: 0.0256 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: 2775367546745822588503047993652382588512277657755480108699830290855659378104663930014105617681772368669677168984188472128162486164535007131103223952412569027060519374860855562370817824233581897145388919422976.0000

<ipython-input-6-e291cb7cd65f>:58: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  d[i] = d[i] - w * d[i-1]
<ipython-input-6-e291cb7cd65f>:58: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  d[i] = d[i] - w * d[i-1]
multiplier: 10 , N_x: 100 , N_t: 400 , k: 0.005 , h^2: 0.0064 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: nan

<ipython-input-6-e291cb7cd65f>:68: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  x[i] = (d[i] - c[i]*x[i+1])/b[i]
<ipython-input-6-e291cb7cd65f>:68: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  x[i] = (d[i] - c[i]*x[i+1])/b[i]
<ipython-input-6-e291cb7cd65f>:324: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  D[1: N_x] = np.array([(A_prev[i-1] * y_tilde_prev[i - 1] + B_prev[i-1] * y_tilde_prev[i] + C_prev[i-1] * y_tilde_prev[i + 1]) for i in range(1, N_x)],
multiplier: 30 , N_x: 300 , N_t: 3600 , k: 0.001 , h^2: 0.0007 , k/h^2:  0.781  --> mean abs err is: nan
-----------------------------------
```

I cannot understand if I am getting anything wrong, or if these problems are intrinsically numerically unstable...

P.S. The script is not very short, but for reference I report it below.

Thanks a lot for help!

```
from math import exp
import numpy as np

# it returns a tridiagonal matrix of the form:
#|b[0]    c[0]                             |
#|a[0]    b[1]    c[1]                     |
#|    .       .       .                    |
#|        .       .       .                |
#|            .       .       .            |
#|                .       .       .        |
#|                    a[n-1]  b[n]   c[n]  |
#|                            a[n]   b[n+1]|
def tridiag_matrix(a, b, c, k_1 = -1, k_2 = 0, k_3 = 1):
    return np.diag(a, k_1) + np.diag(b, k_2) + np.diag(c, k_3)


# it solves a tridiagonal linear system - i.e. form below:
# b[0]*x[0]  +  c[0]*x[1]                                                                     = d[0]
# a[0]*x[0]  +  b[1]*x[1]  +  c[1]*x[2]                                                       = d[1]
#        .             .             .                                                        .   .
#              .             .             .                                                  .   .
#                      .             .             .                                          .   .
#                             .             .             .                                   .   .
#                                    .             .             .                            .   .
#                                           .             .             .                     .   .
#                                                a[n-1]*x[n-1] + b[n] *x[n]  + c[n]  *x[n+1]  = d[n]
#                                                                a[n] *x[n]  + b[n+1]*x[n+1]  = d[n+1]
def solve_tridiagonal_matrix(a, b, c, d):
    b = b.copy()
    d = d.copy()
    n = len(b)
    # we subtract a multiple of the first eq. from the second eq. so that x_0 disappears
    # then we subtract a multiple of the second eq. from the first (new) eq. so that x_1 disappears and so on...
    # keep track of the coefficients of the new reuslting matrix
    # e.g. if we have:
    # 0)     2*x0 + 3*x1                = 2
    # 1)     4*x0 + 8*x1 + 2*x2         = 5
    # 2)            6*x1 + 7*x2 + 1*x3  = 16
    # 3)                   1*x2 + 2*x3  = 17
    # then:
    # eq. 0) is unchanged, new eq.1) is obtained subtracting 2*eq.0) from eq.1); new eq.2) is obtained subtraing 3*new_eq.1) from old eq.2) and so on...
    # 0-new) 2*x0 + 3*x1                = 2     # unchanged
    # 1-new)        2*x1 + 2*x2         = 1     # subtract 2*eq.0 from eq.1 (old)
    # 2-new)               1*x2 + 1*x3  = 1     # subtract 3*eq.1-new from eq.2 (old)
    # 3-new)                      1*x3  = 1     # subtract 1*eq.2-new from eq.3 (old)
    # note that at the end of this process:
    #  i) new array a (below diagonal) becomes 0 (so no calcs needed)
    #  ii) array c is unchanged (so no calcs needed), while new b, d needs to be calculated iteratively
    #  iii) the last variable (x3) can be calculated directly, and the previous ones recoursively backward
    #    (i.e. get x3 from eq.3-new, substitute x3 in eq.2-new and get x_2, and so on...)
    # at this point we can solve for x, using iii) above
    for i in range(1, n):
        # calculate the ratio, w, between the coefficient of x[i-1] in eq. i-1) and the coefficient of x[i-1] in eq. i)
        w = a[i-1] / b[i-1]
        # new eq.i) is obtained as: eq.i (old) - w * eq.i-1 (new)
        # by construction new c[i] = 0, while b[i] and d[i] are calculated:
        b[i] = b[i] - w * c[i-1]
        d[i] = d[i] - w * d[i-1]
    # we obtained the new system in which the lower diagonal is zeroed. We can recoursively calculate the solution x
    x = np.zeros(n, dtype = float)
    # last (new) equation is b[n-1]*x[n-1] = d[n-1]
    # --> we can solve for x[n-1]
    x[n-1] = d[n-1] / b[n-1]
    for i in range(n-2, -1, -1):
        # recoursively we solve each quation, starting from the second-to-last, moving backward to the first
        # at step i, the i-th equation reads: b[i]*x[i] + c[i]*x[i+1] = d[i]
        # x[i+1] being iteratively calculated at previous step, we can solve for x[i]
        x[i] = (d[i] - c[i]*x[i+1])/b[i]
    return x


# it solves a linear system of the form:
# (I call it a crank-nickolson form beacause this algorithm involves the solution of a linear system of this form)
# p[0]*x[0]  +  p[1]*x[1]  +  p[2]*x[2]  + ................ +  p[m1-1]*x[m1-1]                                                                          = d[0]
# a[0]*x[0]  +  b[0]*x[1]  +  c[0]*x[2]                                                                                                                 = d[1]
#               a[1]*x[1]  +  b[1]*x[2]  +  c[1]*x[3]                                                                                                   = d[2]
#                      .             .             .                                                                                                    .   .
#                            .             .             .                                                                                              .   .
#                                  .             .             .                                                                                        .   .
#                                        .             .             .                                                                                  .   .
#                                              .             .             .                                                                            .   .
#                                                    .             .             .                                                                      .   .
#                                                            .             .             .                                                              .   .
#                                                                   .             .             .                                                       .   .
#                                                                          .             .             .                                                .   .
#                                                                                 .             .             .                                         .   .
#                                                                                        .             .             .                                  .   .
#                                                                                              a[n-1]*x[n-1] + b[n]*x[n] + c[n] *x[n+1]                 .   .
#                                                                                                              a[n]*x[n-1] + b[n]*x[n] +    c[n]*x[n+1] = d[n]
#                                                                      q[0]*x[n-m2]  +  q[1]*x[n-m2+1]  + ............. + q[m1-2]*x[n] + q[m2-1]*x[n+1] = d[n+1]



# the below function converts the linear system into a tridiagonal linear system
# it returns the arrays (A, B, C) defining the tridiagonal matrix and the new known vector (D)
def get_trid_arrays(p, q, a, b, c, d):
    # e.g. if we have:
    # 0)                2*x0 + 3*x1 + 5*x2 + 4*x3 + 5*x4 + 5*x5                = 10
    # 1)                1*x0 + 2*x1 + 1*x2                                     = 0
    # 2)                       2*x1 + 2*x2 + 3*x3                              = -4
    # 3)                              2*x2 + 1*x3 + 1*x4                       = 1
    # 4)                                     1*x3 + 3*x4 + 5*x5                = 2
    # 5)                                            4*x4 + 2*x5 + 3*x6         = 24
    # 6)                                                   1*x5 + 4*x6 + 6*x7  = 32
    # 7)                              1*x2 + 3*x3 + 2*x4 + 6*x5 + 7*x6 + 2*x7  = 13

    # STEP 1) subtract eq.4) from eq.0) --> new eq.0) becomes:
    # eq.0-new, step 1) 2*x0 + 3*x1 + 5*x2 + 3*x3 + 2*x4                       = 8     # x5 disappeared!
    # STEP 2) subtract 2*eq.4) from eq. 1-new (step 1) -->  new eq.1) becomes:
    # eq.0-new, step 2) 2*x0 + 3*x1 + 1*x2 + 1*x3                              = 6     # x4 disappeared!
    # and so on... until we  only x0 and x1 appears in the first equation
    # we do the same thing for eq.8, first removing a multiple of eq.2 (x1 disappears), then a multiple of eq.3 (x2 disappears)...
    # ... and so on, until only x6 and x7 remains
    # the resulting system has a tridiagonal form
    # note that intermediate (1 to 6) equations are unaffected
    # only 1) and 8) change, so we need only keep track of p, q, d[0], d[last]
    n = len(a)
    # warning! it is expected that n = len(a) = len(b) = len(c), while len(d) = n+2
    m1 = len(p)
    p = p.copy()
    d = d.copy()
    for i in range(m1-1, 1, -1): # i=m1-1,i=m2-2,...,i=2
        # in eq.0), we need to make disappear first x[m1-1], then x[m1-2],..., and last x[2]
        # (in the example above, p has lenght 6 (from x0 to x5), so we make disappear first x5, then x4, then x3, and last x2
        # iteratively, to make disappear x[i], new eq.0 is obtained subtracting a multiple eq. i-1 from previous eq. 0
        # (check in the example: e.g. i=5, to make disappear x5, we need to subtract eq.4 (=5-1) from eq. 0)
        # the multiple is given by the ratio of the coefficient of x[i] between eq. 0) and eq. i-1)
        # in eq. 0), the coefficient of x[i] is p[i] (e.g. in eq.0 coeff of x5 is p[5]
        # in eq. i-1), the coefficient of x[i] is c[i-2] (e.g. in eq.4 coeff of x5 is c[3])
        # the other two variables in eq. i-1) are x[i-1] and x[i-2], with coefficients b[i-2] and a[i-2], respectively
        # (check in the example: e.g. i=5 the other two variables in eq. 4 are x4 and x3, with coefficients b[3] and a[3], respectively
        w = p[i] / c[i-2]
        p[i] = 0
        p[i-1] = p[i-1] - w * b[i-2]
        p[i-2] = p[i-2] - w * a[i-2]
        d[0] = d[0] - w * d[i-1]
    # we need to do something similar for last equation
    m2 = len(q)
    q = q.copy()
    for i in range(m2-2): #i=0,i=1,...,i=m2-3
        # the # of variables (= # of equations) is len(d) = n+2 - n inner equations, then the first and last equations
        # in last equation, eq. n+1, we need to make disappear first x[n-m2+2], then x[n-m2+2+1],..., x[n-m2+2+i], ..., and last x[n-1] - i ranges from 0 to m2-3
        # (check: in the example above, n=6 (eq. 1 to 6), q has lenght m2=6 (from x2 to x7), so we make disappear first x[2] (1=6-6+2), then x[2+1], ..., and last x5=x[2+3],
        # 3 = m2-3 = 6+3, so that i ranges from 0 to m2-n-3
        # now, the i-th variable of last equation is x[n-m+2+i] and has coefficient of q[i]
        # to make disappear this variable we need to subtract a multiple of eq. n-m2+3 from last equation
        # (check: in the example above, if i=0, to remove x2 (2=n-m2+2+i=6-6+2+0), we need to subtract eq. 3 (3=n-m2+3=6-3+3) from last equation
        # the coefficient of this variable in this eq. is a[n-m2+2+i]
        # (check: in the example above, if i=0, the coefficient of x2 in eq.3 is a[2] (2=n-m2+2+i=6-6+2+0))
        # (check2: in the example above, if i=1, the coefficient of x3 in eq.4 is a[3] (3=n-m2+2+i=6-6+2+1))
        # (check3: if instead last equation had been 2*x4 + 6*x5 + 7*x6 + 2*x7  = 13, then m2 = 4, to remove x4 (4=n-m2+2=6-4+2), we need to subtract eq. 5 from last eq.
        # the coeff of x4 in eq. 5 (i=0) is a[4] (4 = n-m2+2+i = 6-4+2). In total, we need to remove x4, x5=x[4+1], so i ranges from 0 to 1 (1=m2-3= 4-3). OK
        w = q[i] / a[n-m2+i+2]
        q[i] = 0
        q[i+1] = q[i+1] - w * b[n-m2+i+2]  # n-m2+2+i = n-1 --> i = m2-3
        q[i+2] = q[i+2] - w * c[n-m2+i+2]
        d[n+1] = d[n+1] - w * d[n-m2+i+3]  # d[j] from eq. j, j=n-m2+3 (see comments above)
    # now, the resulting tridiagonal matrix is built with a,b,c unchanged and the new p,q:
    # |p[0]   p[1]                                                              |
    # |a[0]   b[0]    c[0]                                                      |
    # |       a[1]    b[1]     c[1]                                             |
    # |             .        .       .                                          |
    # |                      .        .       .                                 |
    # |                               .       .       .                         |
    # |                                       a[n-1]  b[n-1]  c[n-1]            |
    # |                                                 a[n]    b[n]    c[n]    |
    # |                                                         q[m2-2] q[m2-1] |

    # we return below diagonal, diagonal, and upper diagonal arrays

    # A: below diagonal
    # A =       [a[0], a[1], ... , a[n-1], a[n], q[m2-2]]
    A = np.zeros(n+1, dtype=float)
    A[0:n] = a
    A[n] = q[m2-2]
    # B: diagonal
    # B = [p[0], b[0], b[1], ... , b[n-1], b[n], q[m2-1]]
    B = np.zeros(n+2, dtype=float)
    B[1:n+1] = b
    B[0] = p[0]
    B[n+1] = q[m2-1]
    # C: upper diagonal
    # C = [p[1], c[0], c[1], ... , c[n-1], c[n]]
    C = np.zeros(n+1, dtype=float)
    C[1:n+1] = c
    C[0] = p[1]
    D = np.array(d, dtype=float)
    return [A, B, C, D]



def solve_crank_nickolson_linear_system(p, q, a, b, c, d):
    # convert into tridiagonal form - get trid arrays (A,B,C) and new known vector (D)
    [A, B, C, D] = get_trid_arrays(p, q, a, b, c, d)
    # solve the new tridiagonal system
    x = solve_tridiagonal_matrix(A, B, C, D)
    return x


#a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
#b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
#c = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

#d = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
##dd = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype = float)
#p = [1, -3, 3, -1]
#q = [1, -3, 3, -1]

#[A, B, C, D] = get_trid_arrays(p, q, a, b, c, d)

#n = len(d)
#m1 = len(p)
#m2 = len(q)

def get_crank_nickolson_matrix(p, q, a, b, c):
    n = len(a) +2
    m1 = len(p)
    m2 = len(q)
    mat = np.zeros([n,n], dtype = float)
    for i in range(m1):
        mat[0, i] = p[i]
    for i in range(m2):
        mat[n-1, n-m2+i] = q[i]
    for i in range(0, n-2):
        mat[i+1, i] = a[i]
        mat[i+1, i+1] = b[i]
        mat[i+1, i+2] = c[i]
    return mat

#mat2 = tridiag_matrix(A, B, C)
#np.linalg.det(mat2)

#x = solve_tridiagonal_matrix(A, B, C, D)

#mat = get_crank_nickolson_matrix(p, q, a, b, c)
#check = np.matmul(mat, np.transpose(x))

#################################

def my_fct(N_x, N_t, forw_or_backw = "forward", x_bound_cond = "exact_solution", method_if_backward = "backward_equations"):
    # a * y_xx + b * y_x + c * y - y_t = 0
    a = 1
    b = 1
    c = -1
    # solution: y = exp(x+t)

    x_min = -4
    x_max = 4
    T_min = 0
    T_max = 2

    k = (T_max - T_min)/N_t # = d_t
    d_t = k
    h = (x_max - x_min)/N_x # = d_x
    d_x = h

    A_next_val = -(2*k*a - k*h*b)
    A_prev_val =  (2*k*a - k*h*b)

    if forw_or_backw == "forward":
        h_sq_sign = 1
    else:
        h_sq_sign = -1

    B_next_val = (4*pow(h,2)*h_sq_sign + 4*k*a - 2*pow(h,2)*k*c)
    B_prev_val = (4*pow(h,2)*h_sq_sign - 4*k*a + 2*pow(h,2)*k*c)

    C_next_val = -(2*k*a + k*h*b)
    C_prev_val =  (2*k*a + k*h*b)

    A_next = np.array([A_next_val for i in range(1, N_x)], dtype=float)
    A_prev = np.array([A_prev_val for i in range(1, N_x)], dtype=float)

    B_next = np.array([B_next_val for i in range(1, N_x)], dtype=float)
    B_prev = np.array([B_prev_val for i in range(1, N_x)], dtype=float)

    C_next = np.array([C_next_val for i in range(1, N_x)], dtype=float)
    C_prev = np.array([C_prev_val for i in range(1, N_x)], dtype=float)

    y = np.zeros([(N_x+1), (N_t+1)])

    x = np.array([(x_min + i*d_x) for i in range(N_x+1)], dtype=float)
    if forw_or_backw == "forward":
        y_T_min = np.array([exp(x_i+T_min) for x_i in x], dtype=float)
        y_prev = y_T_min
        y[:, 0] = y_T_min
        y_tilde = None
    else:
        y_T_max = np.array([exp(x_i+T_max) for x_i in x], dtype=float)
        if method_if_backward == "y_tilde":
            y_tilde = np.zeros([(N_x + 1), (N_t + 1)])
            y_tilde_prev = y_T_max
            y_tilde[:, 0] = y_T_max
        elif method_if_backward == "backward_equations":
            y_next = y_T_max
            y_tilde = None
        y[:, N_t] = y_T_max

    if x_bound_cond == "exact_solution":
        p = [1, 0]
        q = [0, 1]
    elif x_bound_cond == "third_order_smoothing":
        p = [1, -3, 3, -1]
        q = [1, -3, 3, -1]



    for j in range(1, N_t+1): # j = N_t-1, N_t-2,..., 1, 0
        if forw_or_backw == "forward":
            D = np.zeros(N_x + 1, dtype=float)
            D[1: N_x] = np.array(
                [(A_prev[i - 1] * y_prev[i - 1] + B_prev[i - 1] * y_prev[i] + C_prev[i - 1] * y_prev[i + 1]) for i in
                 range(1, N_x)],
                dtype=float)  # i-1 = 0, 1,..., N_x-3, N_x-2
            if x_bound_cond == "exact_solution":
                D[0] = exp(x_min + (T_min + j * d_t))
                D[N_x] = exp(x_max + (T_min + j * d_t))
            y_next = solve_crank_nickolson_linear_system(p, q, A_next, B_next, C_next, D)
            y[:, j] = y_next
            y_prev = y_next
        else:
            D = np.zeros(N_x + 1, dtype=float)
            if method_if_backward == "y_tilde":
                D[1: N_x] = np.array([(A_prev[i-1] * y_tilde_prev[i - 1] + B_prev[i-1] * y_tilde_prev[i] + C_prev[i-1] * y_tilde_prev[i + 1]) for i in range(1, N_x)],
                                     dtype=float) # i-1 = 0, 1,..., N_x-3, N_x-2
                t_j = N_t - j
                if x_bound_cond == "exact_solution":
                    D[0] = exp(x_min + (T_min + t_j * d_t))
                    D[N_x] = exp(x_max + (T_min + t_j * d_t))
                y_tilde_next = solve_crank_nickolson_linear_system(p, q, A_next, B_next, C_next, D)
                y_tilde[:, j] = y_tilde_next
                y[:, t_j] = y_tilde_next
                y_tilde_prev = y_tilde_next
            elif method_if_backward == "backward_equations":
                D[1: N_x] = np.array([(A_next[i-1] * y_next[i - 1] + B_next[i-1] * y_next[i] + C_prev[i-1] * y_next[i + 1]) for i in range(1, N_x)],
                                     dtype=float) # i-1 = 0, 1,..., N_x-3, N_x-2
                t_j = N_t - j
                if x_bound_cond == "exact_solution":
                    D[0] = exp(x_min + (T_min + t_j * d_t))
                    D[N_x] = exp(x_max + (T_min + t_j * d_t))
                y_prev = solve_crank_nickolson_linear_system(p, q, A_prev, B_next, C_next, D)
                y[:, t_j] = y_prev
                y_next = y_prev

    return [y, y_tilde]


def solve_my_crank(multipliers, forw_or_backw = "forward", x_bound_cond = "exact_solution", method_if_backward = "backward_equations"):

    print("forward or backward:", forw_or_backw, ", x_bound_cond:", x_bound_cond, ", method_if_backward:", method_if_backward)

#    print("N.B. N_x = 10 * multiplier,  N_t = 4 * multiplier")
    for multiplier in multipliers:

        N_x = 10 * multiplier
        N_t = 4 * pow(multiplier, 2)

        x_min = -4
        x_max = 4
        T_min = 0
        T_max = 2

        k = (T_max - T_min) / N_t  # = d_t
        d_t = k
        h = (x_max - x_min) / N_x  # = d_x
        d_x = h


        [y, y_tilde] = my_fct(N_x, N_t, forw_or_backw, x_bound_cond, method_if_backward)

    #    i = int(N_x/2); j = N_t; x_i = x_min+i*d_x; t_j = T_min+j*d_t; print("i: ", i, ", j: ", j, "  -->  exp(x_i+t_j): ", exp(x_i+t_j), ", y[i, j]): ", y[i, j])

        mean_err = np.mean([np.mean([abs(exp(x_min+i*d_x + T_min+j*d_t) - y[i,j]) for j in range(N_t+1)]) for i in range(N_x+1)])
        mean_abs_errs.append(mean_err)

        print("multiplier:", multiplier, ", N_x:", N_x, ", N_t:", N_t, ", k:", "{:.3f}".format(k), ", h^2:", "{:.4f}".format(pow(h,2)), ", k/h^2: ", "{:.3f}".format(k/pow(h,2)), " --> mean abs err is:", "{:.4f}".format(mean_err))
        print()
    print("-----------------------------------")


multipliers = [1, 3, 5, 10, 30]
mean_abs_errs = []

forw_or_backw = "forward"
solve_my_crank(multipliers, forw_or_backw)

forw_or_backw = "forward"
x_bound_cond = "third_order_smoothing"
solve_my_crank(multipliers, forw_or_backw, x_bound_cond)

forw_or_backw = "backward"
x_bound_cond = "exact_solution"
method_if_backward = "backward_equations"
solve_my_crank(multipliers, forw_or_backw, x_bound_cond, method_if_backward)

forw_or_backw = "backward"
x_bound_cond = "exact_solution"
method_if_backward = "y_tilde"
solve_my_crank(multipliers, forw_or_backw, x_bound_cond, method_if_backward)
```